# Locally hosted Django traffic analytics

Tags: python, django, google-analytics, traffic

is there any known way to track locally hosted django web? I want to know who is using web, how many unique users, what is the most visited resource etc. 
 I would use Google Analytics or smth similar, but my project is deployed offline and has to access to internet. So i need to track the specific IP Django is deployed on. 
I was trying to install Piwik, since it can be installed on the machine, but i didnt succeed to install mysql on my raspberry pi. 

I am working on raspberry pi 2 wheezy, python 3

Comment: Use a different db then? Like [sqllite3](https://github.com/josepsanzcamp/sqlite-for-piwik)

Comment: Piwik [requires] (https://piwik.org/docs/requirements/) mysql :(